# CodeIgniter Tank Auth library: allow spaces in user name

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

Is there any way to allow spaces in user names `Name Givenname` and characters like `ščťžýáíéúô` (any UTF-8 characters) in CodeIgniter Tank Auth library?

I was browse code but I do not know hot to allow it? And aloso I need to allow duplicate usernames (need only email to be unique).

**EDIT:**

When I trying to register new user I get this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhxEO.png
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Tank Auth places any restrictions on spaces/characters in the username, it's more likely to be the collation on your `users` table. Tank Auth uses SQL `LOWER()` functions to compare usernames to input, so SQL `LOWER('whatever is in the DB')` must equal PHP `strtolower('whatever the user entered')`.

If your `users` table is not defined with collation `UTF8_GENERAL_CI`, try changing it to that.

If that doesn't fix it, the code in `models/tank_auth/users.php` is very simple, so you can easily adapt it to meet your needs.

Comment: This is probably due to your validation rules. Check your auth controller, in the register function, and see what validation filters are applied to the username field. In particular, look for `alpha_dash` or `alpha_dash_dot`. If you see those, remove them and try again.